# How can one estimate $(1/2)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_N|dx$,here DN is the Dirichlet kernel

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

The Dirichlet Kernel
$$D_N =\frac{\sin(N+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}$$
How to show this 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\pi}^{\pi}|D_N|dx=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\log N+O(1)$$

Comment: It  is found on the Stein's Fourier Analysis,Page 66

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550283/about-the-order-of-the-l1-norm-of-the-dirichlet-kernel?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563402/estimate-the-integral-of-the-absolute-value-of-the-dirichlet-kernel?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024719/divergence-int-pi-pi-d-nxdx-for-dirichlet-kernel-as-n-to-infty?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you ,it's a great help !